# what is the correct syntax to interpolate an object into a double quoted string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
"please contact your <%=@user.name %>  mentor"
```

I am using the above syntax and it is wrong.

Can anyone please tell me the correct syntax for interpolating `@user.name` into a string using `"  "`.

Comment: if we answered your question can you accept one of the answers please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"please contact your #{@user.name }  mentor"
```

if you just want to call `.to_s` on `@user` you can do

```
"please contact your #@user  mentor"
```

and omit the `{}`

`<%=...%>` is for eRB files, use `"#{}"` to substitute in quotes

Answer (score 3):

The `<%= %>` format is for erb template files. If you want to do string interpolation within standard Ruby code, use the `#{ }` format instead.

```
"please contact your #{@user.name} mentor"
```

Comment: This is for double quote..what is the syntax for signle quote??

Comment: You can't do it with single quotes, Ruby will only apply interpolation with double quotes.

Comment: 'please contact your ' + @user.name + ' mentor' - for single quotes :), but this is not interpolation, this is concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct syntax for an erb template. for ruby it is

```
"please contact your #{@user.name} mentor"
```